# Passing an attribute from one portlet to another via session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, liferay

I am using Spring-MVC and Liferay and I need to pass an attribute from one portlet to another through session.

Do I need to use `HttpSession` instead of `PortletSession`, or is the `APPLICATION_SCOPE` setting enough?

I need to do two things

- set the parameter to a shared/application session
- read it from the session and pass it to the view using Spring `Model`

I am trying to do the first like this:

```
PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession();
session.setAttribute("foo", request.getParameter("foo"), 
    PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
response.sendRedirect("/somewhere");
```

And then the second like this:

```
@RequestMapping
public String view(PortletSession session, Model model){
    if (session.getAttribute("foo") != null) {
        model.addAttribute("foo", session.getAttribute("foo").toString());
    }
return "somewhere/view";
}
```

And then I try to display it in my JSP simply by using `${foo}` but nothing shows up.

Can you share any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to get the attribute from the session in a bad way. I need to specify the scope while retrieving the attribute from `PortletSession` as well.

Changing it to

```
@RequestMapping
public String view(RenderRequest request, Model model){
    PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("foo", 
            PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE) != null) {
        model.addAttribute("foo", session.getAttribute("foo", 
            PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE).toString());
    }
    return "somewhere/view";
}
```

fixed the problem.

Also it is necessary to set the private session attributes setting to false in `liferay-portlet.xml` in the module of **both portlets** like this:

```
<portlet>
    <!-- ..some previous settings and then -->
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
</portlet>
```

Doc: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication